# »Weil« zwischen zwei Adjektiven

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction

Ich bin eben auf folgenden Satz aus *Die Geschichte von Herrn Sommer*  gestoßen:

> Sie verschafften mir süße, weil überflüssige Sorgen.

Mich überrascht, dass *weil* zwischen zwei Adjektiven steht, ohne einen Nebensatz einzuleiten. Ist diese Nutzung standardsprachlich, gehoben oder umgangssprachlich und ist das überhaupt richtiges Deutsch?

Comment: Ein Blick in den Online-Duden (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/weil#Bedeutungb) hätte dir folgenden Beispielsatz beschert: *eine schlechte, weil lückenhafte Darstellung*. (Man könnte auch *eine schlechte, weil unrecherchierte Frage* als Beispielsatz nehmen).  Du hättest auch sofort gesehen, dass dieses Beispiel weder mit "gehoben" noch "umgangssprachlich" markiert ist.

Comment: Es funktioniert auch mit Adverbien: *ein guter, oft teurer Rat*

Comment: Ein gutes, weil der schönen Literatur entnommenes Beispiel!

Comment: @Janka Ich wäre mir nicht sicher, ob das Beispiel "*ein guter, oft teurer Rat*" nicht einfach eine Aufzählung ist, da man die Elemente bei gleichbleibender Bedeutung auch einzeln verwenden kann: "*ein guter Rat*", "*ein oft teurer Rat*".

Comment: Dass es mit Adverbien funktioniert, kann nicht überraschen, denn Adverbien stehen häufig bei Adjektiven. Es funktioniert aber auch mit anderen Konjunktionen als mit *weil*: *Ein interessanter, wenngleich riskanter Vorschlag.*

Comment: `Ein schönes, aber teures Buch.` `Ein kranker, fast toter Baum.` `Eine gewagte, vielleicht falsche These.` `Eine vereiste, damit unbrauchbare Klinke.` Für mich sind das Kausaladverbien, die mehr Präzision bringen. Stilistisch setz ich sie ein, wenn ich beide Adjektive erwähnen will statt nur eins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Beispielsatz kann durchaus der Standardsprache zugerechnet werden.

Man überzeuge sich zunächst, dass die folgenden, vielleicht vertrauter wirkenden Beispiele demselben Bauplan folgen: *der liebe, aber unfolgsame Hund; der sympathische und hilfsbereite Nachbar*, wobei als Konnektor hier jeweils eine Konjunktion (statt von Haus aus subjunktivem "weil") fungiert, was aber an der Grundstruktur nichts ändert.

Sprachlich handelt es sich beim in der Frage zitierten Satz um ein Beispiel für das Phänomen, dass die Bedeutungsargumente bestimmter (nicht aller!) Konnektoren nicht unbedingt "Satzstrukturen" (bzw. Ellipsen hiervon) sein müssen, sondern auch in Form von Propositionen vorliegen können, die ihre Bedeutung aus Adjektiv- und/oder Partizipialattributen beziehen. Aus dem Schulunterricht könnte man ja vielleicht den Eindruck gewinnen, dass Junktionen zwingend in irgendeiner Form zwischen zwei Propositionen mit Satzprädikaten stehen - "Ich *mag* dich und du *magst* mich", "Er *hilft* ihr, weil sie so schön *ist*", etc. Das muss nicht so sein - hier sehen wir ein Beispiel dafür.

Das Phänomen ist verbreitet (vgl. Hennig, Explizite und elliptische Junktion in der Attribution, in: dies./Niemann, Junktion in der Attribution, 2015, S. 23 ff.). Speziell mit "weil"-Konstruktionen wie im Ausgangsbeispiel befasst sich Breindl, FS Strecker, 2012, S. 153-158: ["Er ist sympathisch, weil menschlich" — "Weil" als koordinierende Konjunktion?](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=132)